# How to check the continuousness of a string array & if it is not in the continuousness, then remove it?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Ok, here is my requirement, I have a following table:

```
ID-Category-No
22-Software-1
45-Software-2
78-Hardware-3
48-Software-4
11-Hardware-5
91-Service -6
95-Service -7
93-Software-8
```

I select all data with order by No, & put it into a String[], then put this String[] int a list

So I will have:

```
String[] s1={"22","Software","1"};
String[] s2={"45","Software","2"};
.....
List<String[]> myL=new ArrayList<String[]>();
myL.add(s1);
myL.add(s2);
....
```

Now, from `myL`, I just want to take all the String[] that has Category in a continuousness, if the category is not in the continuousness, then remove it.

Note that: we must take the category that appear first & all of the same category that follows it in a continuousness. So we need to do something so that the final `myL` will contain only these String[]

```
ID-Category-No
22-Software-1
45-Software-2
78-Hardware-3
91-Service -6
95-Service -7
```

Comment: When you say continuum, do you mean set?

Comment: no, it just means that I want to take the rows that are continue, nothing relating to set

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, continuous categories

Comment: This seems like a bizarre thing to want to do. What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: it's my company project, my boss wants it. I can't tell

Comment: Tell your boss to explain what he wants and let the programmer provide an actually logical solution... This is just weird.

Comment: it's a secret. Like sometimes the user didn't put the category in a right other so he doesn't want to show the wrong order rows. That's it. He just wants to keep the rows that in right order no matter how user input the data.

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense for the computer to sort the rows so they would always be sorted correctly?

Comment: Our system can't sort cos it got some constraints & a lot of things relating to it so we can't sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to complicate the task, you should really create a class, say `Job`, to store those attributes, rather than using a `String[]`. And then maintain a `List<Job>`.

In the `Job` class, you should implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, comparing based on `category`. So, the class will look like this:

```
class Job {
    private int id;
    private String category;
    private int no;

    public Job(int id, String category, int no) {
        this.id = id;
        this.category = category;
        this.no = no;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Job)) return false;
        return category.equals(((Job)obj).category);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return category.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + id + ", " + category + ", " + no + "]\n";
    }
}
```

Now, you can have a `List<Job>`:

```
Job s1= new Job(22,"Software",1);
Job s2= new Job(45,"Software",2);
Job s3= new Job(78, "Hardware", 3);
Job s4= new Job(48, "Software", 4);
Job s5= new Job(11, "Hardware", 5);
Job s6= new Job(91, "Service", 6);
Job s7 =new Job(95, "Service", 7);
Job s8 = new Job(93, "Software", 8);

List<Job> list=new ArrayList<Job>(Arrays.asList(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8));
```

Create a temporary `ArrayList`, which will store your result:

```
List<Job> contiguous = new ArrayList<Job>();

/* The boolean variable will be used to track whether the sequence till
   now is contiguous or not */
/* Everytime we add a new unique job, a new contiguous sequence is started.
   So, we will set this variable to `true` */   
boolean isContiguousTillNow = false;
```

Here's the loop doing the actual job:

```
for (Job job: list) {

    if (contiguous.isEmpty()) {
        /* First job added. Set 'isContiguousTillNow' to 'true' */
        contiguous.add(job);
        isContiguousTillNow = true;

    } else if (isContiguousTillNow && contiguous.get(contiguous.size() - 1).equals(job)) {
        /* The sequence has been contiguous till now, and the last job 
           added is equal to current job. Add the job. */
        contiguous.add(job);

    } else if (!contiguous.contains(job)) {
        /* Sequence is either broken here, or was already broken */
        /* But since the list doesn't already contains this job, add it,
           and this starts a new contiguous sequence. So, set it to 'true' */
        contiguous.add(job);
        isContiguousTillNow = true;

    } else {
        /* ContigousSequence stops here. So, set it to 'false' */
        isContiguousTillNow = false;
    }
}
```

And then your `contiguous` list will contain the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void methodX() {
    String[] s1 = {"22", "Software", "1"};
    String[] s2 = {"45", "Software", "2"};
    String[] s3 = {"78", "Hardware", "3"};
    String[] s4 = {"48", "Software", "4"};
    String[] s5 = {"11", "Hardware", "5"};
    String[] s6 = {"91", "Service", "6"};
    String[] s7 = {"95", "Service", "7"};
    String[] s8 = {"93", "Software", "8"};
    ArrayList<String[]> myL = new ArrayList<>();
    myL.add(s1);
    myL.add(s2);
    myL.add(s3);
    myL.add(s4);
    myL.add(s5);
    myL.add(s6);
    myL.add(s7);
    myL.add(s8);
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet();
    boolean continued = false;
    String category = "";
    ArrayList<String[]> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String[] s : myL) {
        if (!continued) {
            if (set.add(s[1])) {
                continued = true;
                category = s[1];
            } else {
                continued = false;
                toRemove.add(s);
            }
        } else {
            if (s[1].equals(category)) {

            } else {
                if (set.add(s[1])) {
                    continued = true;
                    category = s[1];
                } else {
                    continued = false;
                    toRemove.add(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    myL.removeAll(toRemove);
    for (String[] list : myL) {
        System.out.println(list[0] + "-" + list[1] + "-" + list[2]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's removing approach. I've coded a retaining approach.

```
public void myMethod()
{
String[] s1 = {"22", "Software", "1"};
String[] s2 = {"45", "Software", "2"};
String[] s3 = {"78", "Hardware", "3"};
String[] s4 = {"48", "Software", "4"};
String[] s5 = {"11", "Hardware", "5"};
String[] s6 = {"91", "Service", "6"};
String[] s7 = {"95", "Service", "7"};
String[] s8 = {"93", "Software", "8"};
ArrayList<String[]> myL = new ArrayList<>();
myL.add(s1);
myL.add(s2);
myL.add(s3);
myL.add(s4);
myL.add(s5);
myL.add(s6);
myL.add(s7);
myL.add(s8);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String[]> retainList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String previous = "";
for (String[] s : myL) 
{
    if(list.size() == 0)
    {   
        previous = s[1];
        add(list, retainList, s);
        continue;
    }
    if(previous.equals(s[1]))
        add(list, retainList, s);
    else
        if(!list.contains(s[1]))
            add(list, retainList, s);
    previous = s[1];
}
myL.retainAll(retainList);
for(String[] r : myL)
    System.out.println(r[0] + "-" + r[1] + "-" + r[2]) ;
}

public void add(List<String> t, List<String[]> r, String[] s)
{
t.add(s[1]);
r.add(s);
}
```